# how to add maven snapshot jar into aws EMR spark on startup?

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, apache-spark

I'm very new to Maven and AWS EMR.

I have created a custom AMI that has Maven installed and created a snapshot JAR through `mvn install`. The JAR is not Spark job or anything like that, it is simply package for Spark. My `.m2` directory is located in `/home/ec2-user/`.

I then use the custom AMI to launch EMR, how do I add that snapshot jar in startup? As I don't want to add jar through `spark-submit` after EMR is launched. Can I add jar through Configuration, i.e. spark-defaults.conf or spark-env.sh? I have read something that you can setup `spark.jars my_jar.jar` in spark-default.conf, do I need to provide the full path to my jar (i.e. `/home/ec2-user/.m2/.../.../my_jar.jar`)?

Thank you.